# how to hard rest my pronto tech axius series 7' quad core andriod

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

How do I hard reset my android pronto tec axius 7' quad core PC tablet  ?? When my touch screen stopped working..I have tried holding down on/off button and +- volume keys and it does not do anything

Answer (score 0):

To give your device much a needed *"hard rest"*, you must physically apply sufficient pressure to **all** hardware buttons located around your device including the **power button** and the **volume toggles (both!)** for a few minutes.

This should be done after several hours of charging to ensure your device has the capacity to respond.